# Can someone explain where the "messages" key comes from?

Tags: javascript

I am following a tutorial and I understood everything up until everything beyond where I declared the let variable.

```
function submitMessage(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    const fullName = document.getElementById("fullName").value;
    const feedbackType = document.getElementById("feedbackType").value;
    const comment = document.getElementById("comment").value;
  
    const messageObject = {
        email,
        fullName,
        feedbackType,
        comment
    };

    let currentMessages = [];

    if (window.sessionStorage.getItem("messages")) {
        currentMessages =
            JSON.parse(
                window.sessionStorage.getItem("messages")
            );
    }
  
    currentMessages.push(messageObject);
  
    window.sessionStorage.setItem(
        "messages",
        JSON.stringify(currentMessages)
    );
}
```

Comment: It appears to come in on this line `window.sessionStorage.setItem()` when it's stored to storage. It can be spelled anything valid, for example, try renaming it to `EMafini` and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

You're setting the `"messages"` key for the session storage here:

```js
window.sessionStorage.setItem(
    "messages", // arbitrary key name
    JSON.stringify(currentMessages) // value to store for this key
);
```

Answer (score 0):

`let  currentMessage` is an empty array that will hold `messageObject` variable expressed few row before.

After `currentMessage` there is a step that setup a session store that we going to call "messages".

The `window.sessionStorage` function is used to save some data inside the browser, in our case `currentMessage`. In this way if your refreshed the browser page you will able to get the last data save in `window.sessionStorage`.

So in the first step this function try to get messages object from the session storage that we have e called `messages`.

Then, one fetched it will push the `currentMessage` inside it with `setItem`, so after you reload the browser you will be able to retrieve the array passing through the session storage `getItem` and to get this value it need to search inside some key and the key is `messages`, in other word the key in the session storage that can hold our array.